# npm start not working after create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

I am trying to create a react app with the below steps:

1. npm install -g create-react-app
2. create-react-app my-app
3. cd my-app
4. npm start

And I get this error:

[image]

In error have suggestion to remove webpack dependency but i cant do that because in file package.json dun have that. Here my package.json

[image]

For additional information:

- i am using windows 10
- npm 6.4.1
- create-react-app version 2.0.3
- node v8.12.0

Comment: Did you try the step to fix the dependency tree as the error message suggested?

Comment: i cant follow that suggestion because in package.json that created automatically doesnt contain webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Just do following steps:
- delete package-lock.json.
- delete node_modules.
- npm install.

Or

Just try steps mentioned in the error log and you will be fine .
[image]

Comment: in package.json dont have webpack.  Only have   "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.4"
  },

Comment: it's fine. After deleting (package-lock.json file + node_modules folder) and doing npm install will work just fine. No need care about webpack if it was not there.

Comment: Thank for suggestion. Just now i already try - delete package-lock.json.
- delete node_modules.
- npm install. But Problem still appear.

Answer (score 1):

Do step number 6 and delete that babel loader or webpack folder and you will be good afterwards. Chances are you have an outdated web pack or babel that you installed in a previous project.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this very issue, and turns out to be something simple

The part of the log that says about there being a

"a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree"

looks to be the same case for you.  I think you may have ran `npm install` at some point under D:\bolehDiHapus and so have node_modules installed further up the tree that you meant.

I simply changed the name of D:\bolehDiHapus\node_modules (probably best to just delete it) and hey presto `npm start` works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, first it started saying we found the wrong version farther up in the tree, and then i had to delete webpack up there, and then i had install their "required version" even if it is lower than latest.

`npm install webpack@version --save`

in your case: `npm install --save webpack@4.19.1`